# Using position independent code without GOT

Tags: c, arm

I am having a problem compiling multiple PIC files without the Global offset table.

When compiling the first file onefile.c with the following parameters the assembly does not include reference to the GOT:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe first.c -nosdlib -fPIE -march=armv7-a -o first.o

first.c

```
void function();
int main();

int main()
{
    void* function_pointer;
    function_pointer = &function;
}

void function()
{

}
```

Assembly:

```
.text:00008000 ; int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
.text:00008000                 EXPORT main
.text:00008000 main
.text:00008000
.text:00008000 var_8           = -8
.text:00008000 var_s0          =  0
.text:00008000
.text:00008000                 STR             R11, [SP,#-4+var_s0]!
.text:00008004                 ADD             R11, SP, #0
.text:00008008                 SUB             SP, SP, #0xC
.text:0000800C                 LDR             R3, =(function - 0x8018)
.text:00008010                 ADD             R3, PC, R3 ; function
.text:00008014                 STR             R3, [R11,#var_8]
.text:00008018                 MOV             R3, #0
.text:0000801C                 MOV             R0, R3
.text:00008020                 SUB             SP, R11, #0
.text:00008024                 LDR             R11, [SP+var_s0],#4
.text:00008028                 BX              LR
.text:00008028 ; End of function main
```

Notice how in address 0x8010 the register R3 has the address of the function "function" without using the GOT.

But when splitting the file to multiple .c and .h files the result is changing

> arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe twofiles1.c twofiles2.c -nostdlib -fPIE
>   -march=armv7-a -o twofiles.o

twofiles1.c:

```
#include "twofiles1.h"

int main()
{
    void* function_pointer;
    function_pointer = &function;
}
```

twofiles1.h:

```
#include "twofiles2.h"

int main();
```

twofiles2.c:

```
void function()
{

}
```

twofiles2.h:

```
void function();
```

assembly:

```
.text:00008000 ; int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
.text:00008000                 EXPORT main
.text:00008000 main
.text:00008000
.text:00008000 var_8           = -8
.text:00008000 var_s0          =  0
.text:00008000
.text:00008000                 STR             R11, [SP,#-4+var_s0]!
.text:00008004                 ADD             R11, SP, #0
.text:00008008                 SUB             SP, SP, #0xC
.text:0000800C                 LDR             R2, =(_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ - 0x8018)
.text:00008010                 ADD             R2, PC, R2 ; _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
.text:00008014                 LDR             R3, =(function_ptr - 0x18054)
.text:00008018                 LDR             R3, [R2,R3] ; function
.text:0000801C                 STR             R3, [R11,#var_8]
.text:00008020                 MOV             R3, #0
.text:00008024                 MOV             R0, R3
.text:00008028                 SUB             SP, R11, #0
.text:0000802C                 LDR             R11, [SP+var_s0],#4
.text:00008030                 BX              LR
.text:00008030 ; End of function main
```

Notice how the address of the function "function" is calculated **with** the GOT. That is what I would like to refrain from
Is there any solution of achieving the same assembly as the first result?

Comment: Only if you compile your program as a single translation unit can you avoid the GOT.

Answer (score 3):

Compiler see one module at a time, so different compilation units mandate GOT to be used.

About PIC code [GCC man](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) says

> **-fpic**
>
> Generate position-independent code (PIC) suitable for use in a shared library, if supported for the target machine. **Such code accesses all constant addresses through a global offset table (GOT). The dynamic loader resolves the GOT entries when the program starts (the dynamic loader is not part of GCC; it is part of the operating system).** If the GOT size for the linked executable exceeds a machine-specific maximum size, you get an error message from the linker indicating that -fpic does not work; in that case, recompile with -fPIC instead. (These maximums are 8k on the SPARC, 28k on AArch64 and 32k on the m68k and RS/6000. The x86 has no such limit.)
> Position-independent code requires special support, and therefore works only on certain machines. For the x86, GCC supports PIC for System V but not for the Sun 386i. Code generated for the IBM RS/6000 is always position-independent.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: Is there any convenient method of splitting files and still not use the GOT?

Comment: AFAIK no, there isn't.